# Writing Text File in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a set of values to written into a text file.

Suppose I have a field value of size 10 but the field size is fixed as 20, so when the next field comes, it should be inserted at position 21, filling the remainig 10 spaces of the first field with empty spaces.

Can anyone please let me know how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `strLfix` would be the most likely fix. A similar function `strRfix` right aligns the text to a specified lenght.

Also remember to set the output field delimiter to the empty string. The default of one blank space is not relevant here.

```
static void TextIoTest(Args _args)
{
    TextIo f = new TextIo(@"C:\Temp\test.txt", 'w');
    ;
    f.outFieldDelimiter('');
    f.outRecordDelimiter('\r\n');
    f.write(    strLfix("abc",20), '|', strRfix("xyz",15), '|', 117);
    f.writeExp([strLfix("abc",20), '|', strRfix("xyz",15), '|', 117]);
    f.write(); // To force CR NL
}
```

The job opens the file for writing (truncates existing file or creates a new file), set the field and record delimiters, then writes the same line twice (using two different calls). The last call to `write` appends the record delimiter, this may or may not be important depending on the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strrep`, `substr`, and `strpoke`, please find an example in `\Classes\VendOutPaymRecord_UK_BACS\output`.